# GetModuleHandleEx fails on csrsrv.dll

Tags: c++, winapi

In my current project I need some functions exported from ntdll.dll and csrsrv.dll.

There is no problem with getting handle for ntdll and pointer to functions. But when I try get handle for csrsrv.dll function fails with error code "File not found". I've tried to specify full path to file, but it dose not change a thing.

Code for my load function from dll function:

```
PVOID GetFunctionFromDll(const std::string& _sModuleName,const std::string& _sFnName)
{
    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    PVOID ptrFn = NULL;

    if(!GetModuleHandleEx(0,_sModuleName.c_str(),&hModule))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ptrFn = GetProcAddress(hModule, _sFnName.c_str());

    FreeLibrary(hModule); // preventing handle leakage

    return ptrFn;
}
```

Any ideas why does it fail with csrsrv.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetModuleHandleEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not load the DLL. From the linked reference page:

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module and increments the module's reference count unless GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT is specified. **The module must have been loaded by the calling process.**

The `csrsrv.dll` must not be in memory when the call is made and the `ntdll.dll` will be in memory, and the call succeeds.

Suggest using [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) outside of the function to ensure the DLL remains in memory beyond the function call, guaranteeing that the address returned by `GetFunctionFromDll()` remains valid.

Comment: Indeed it just was not loaded to memory. Thanks for pointing the sentence that i've missed in documentation